# Dimension of the anti-symmetric tensor

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

**Question:** I can't understand why the dimension of the space of anti-symmetric $p$-tensor of a vector space $V$ is $n \choose p$ ($dimV=n$). I thought this only count the basis like $\omega(e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}\cdots)$, but doesn't $\omega(e_{i_1}, e_{i_1}\cdots)$ need to be in the basis?

**Some definition:** 
Tensor: a multilinear map $T:V\times V\cdots V \to \mathbb{R}$
Anti-symmetric $p$-tensor: the tensor $\omega$ such that $\omega(x_1, \cdots ,x_s, \cdots ,x_l, \cdots , x_k)=-\omega(x_1, \cdots ,x_l, \cdots ,x_s, \cdots , x_k)$, with $p$ $V$s times together as the left of the arrow.

Comment: Do you know what anti-symmetric means?

Comment: $\omega(x_1,\cdots ,x_s, \cdots, x_l, \cdots, x_k)=-\omega(x_1,\cdots ,x_l, \cdots, x_s, \cdots, x_k)$?

Comment: This is not what I expected given your first sentence. What is an antisymmetric $p$-tensor? You're defining it for multilinear mappings on $V$.

Comment: My comprehension is that tensor is a multilinear map $T:V\times V\cdots\times V \to R$, and antisymmetric $p$-tensor is the tensor that satisfy the property above., with p Vs times together as the left of the arrow.

Comment: OK, so your language and what you posted in the question say something different. You were talking about bases for $V$, not for the multilinear maps on $V$. For multilinear maps, you need the dual basis for $V^*$ in order to construct a basis. Can you please revise your question to include the precise definitions of everything you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguty. I've edited the question. Is that better now?

Comment: OK, I'm still not happy. Your "count the basis like $\omega(e_{i_1},\dots)$" doesn't really make sense. But to address your question, if you repeat $e_j$ then $\omega(e_j,e_j,\dots)=0$ by skew-symmetry. Why is this? So you must use distinct $e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_k}$, and then, again by skew-symmetry, you may reorder to get $i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k$. You still have to work on the space of multilinear maps to define a basis there.

Comment: That's...what I wanted to ask. I didn't realized that repeated $e_j$ will make the map equals to zero before. Now I've understood this. And as for the basis of the space of multilinear maps I thought I just need to define the map that maps each basis that we talked before to 1 and others to zero? Similar to dual basis.

Comment: Right, you can do that. Good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the context of anti-symmetric p-tensors, the dimension (np) is based on combinations rather than permutations. This means that repeating indices, as in (ei1,ei1⋯), are not considered distinct elements in the basis.

For example, in a 2-dimensional vector space V with basis (e1, e2), the basis for an anti-symmetric 2-tensor (also known as a 2-form) would include terms like e1∧e2 but not e1∧e1 since it is zero due to anti-symmetry.

The (np) dimension accounts for choosing p distinct elements from n without regard to the order, avoiding repetitions in the basis.

Comment: Please learn to post in MathJax.